# How to use foreign keys to retrieve data || laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I am using laravel 5.3, and MySQL. I was trying to use foreign keys to retrieve data from a different table. The field that will be displaying data I got from the other table "domaines" is a drop-down list, but it's always empty.

This is my ProjectController :

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
         $projects = Project::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);

         return view('projects.index',compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $domaines = Domaine::pluck('name', 'id');

        return view('projects.create', compact('domaines'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $domaine_id = Domaine::all()->pluck('name', 'id');     

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'code' => 'required',       
            'domaine_id' => 'required'
            ]);

        Project::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('projects.index') //???? add compact or not ??
                    ->with('success','Project created successfully');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);

        return view('projects.show',compact('project'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);
        return view('projects.edit',compact('project'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'code' => 'required',
            'domaine_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        Project::find($id)->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
                    ->with('success','Project updated successfully');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Project::find($id)->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
                    ->with('success','Project deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

and this is show.blade.php :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Domaine:</strong>
        {{ $project->domaine_id }}
    </div>
</div>
```

create.blade.php :

```
<select class="form-control" name="domaine_id">
            @if (empty($domaine_id))                                    
                Whoops! Something went wrong                            
            @else
            @foreach($domaines as $domaine)
              <option value="{{$domaine->id}}">{{$domaine->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            @endif
</select>
```

model Project.php :

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use App\Domaine;
 class Pro extends Model
 {
     public $fillable = ['title','code','domaine_id'];
 }
```

migration : create_projects_table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id', true);
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('code'); 
        $table->integer('domaine_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('domaine_id')->references('id')->on('domaines');        
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
}
```

Any idea why the list is always empty ? I have seeder so tables in DB are not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" name="domaine_id">
            @if (empty($domaine_id))                                    
                Whoops! Something went wrong                            
            @else
            @foreach($domaines as $domaine)
              <option value="{{$domaine->id}}">{{$domaine->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            @endif
</select>
```

in this section of code you check empty($domaine_id) but from your controller, you didn't pass this variable during view load.

```
public function create()
{
   $domaines = Domaine::pluck('name', 'id');
   return view('projects.create', compact('domaines'));
}
```

you can change the if condition like below:

```
<select class="form-control" name="domaine_id">
            @if (!count($domaines) > 0)                                    
                Whoops! Something went wrong                            
            @else
            @foreach($domaines as $domaine)
              <option value="{{$domaine->id}}">{{$domaine->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            @endif
</select>
```

By the way use all() instead of pluck in the controller.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working. Well, the way it's displaying data, isn't what I really wanted (something like that : {"domaine":"name_domaine1","id":1} ). But, at least the list is no longer empty.

Comment: Welcome hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why the list is always empty?

Since you're using `pluck()` method, you should iterate list like this:

```
@foreach($domaines as $id => $domaine)
     <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $domaine }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Or just use `get()` or `all()` without `pluck()`:

```
$domaines = Domaine::get(['name', 'id']);
```

Comment: I tried all() but, it doesn't change anything. And get() generate this error :

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\PC\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 123 and defined

Comment: @Naj did you try to iterate `pluck()` result as I've shown? Also, try to use this when using `get()`: `get(['name', 'id'])`

Comment: Yes, I iterated pluck() results, and replace pluck() by get()

Comment: @Naj at the same time? You should use `pluck()` with the iteration code I provided or you should use `get()` and iterate data as you did before. If you did this right, but still get any error when using `pluck()`, please post it here.

Comment: No, not at the same time. None of these methods is working :(